# A loop to compare all string values of an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Let's say you have a string array **arr** with 3 strings in it. To compare its values, you would simply do the following:

```
if (arr[0].equals(arr[1]) && arr[0].equals(arr[2] && arr[1].equals(arr[2]) {
    return true;
}
```

But what if that array had hundreds of strings? What is the best way to compare all the values?

I thought of using **for loops** but Java does not allow loops inside a conditional. Any ideas?

Comment: But it does allow conditionals inside a loop...

Comment: Also, your third check is not needed.  IF a == b AND a == c, then we already know that b == c, due to [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).  It's enough to check whether each element is equal to the first.

Comment: A better approach would be to just not put duplicate strings in your data structure. Which means you should look to use a hashtable or something similar. Ends up with O(1) efficiency.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @azurefrog I am trying to put a loop inside a conditional, not a conditional inside a loop. For instance, if(for loop){}

Comment: @LawrenceLelo thats what methods containing for loops and return booleans are for. `if (someMethodReturnsTrue() )` where the method has a for loop.

Answer (score 5):

How about this 1-liner:

```
return Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count() == 1;
```

This code neatly handles empty (but not null) arrays, returning `false` if empty.

If you want to return `true` when the array is empty, change the test to:

```
return Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count() < 2;
```

Comment: What about in the case of a 2-dimensional array, and let's say you intend on only comparing the values of the second row for an example.

Comment: would 'return Arrays.stream(arr[1]).distinct().count() == 1;' work? or no?

Comment: Nope. I just tested this with a 1D array and works fine. But it doesn't work with a 2D array.

Comment: Did you change the 'arr' to 'arr[1]'?

Comment: I have. The result was return Arrays.stream(arr[1]).distinct().count() == 1;

Answer (score 1):

If the array could be of any dimension, then the [`Objects.deepEquals()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) might be of help:

```
boolean allEqual = Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(a -> Objects.deepEquals(arr[0], a));
```

Even better:

```
boolean allEqual = Arrays.stream(arr, 1, arr.length) // bounds check left
    .allMatch(a -> Objects.deepEquals(arr[0], a));   // to the reader :)
```

Test:

```
String[][] arr = {
    {"a", "a"},
    {"a", "a"},
    {"a", "a"}};

boolean allEqual = Arrays.stream(arr, 1, arr.length)
        .allMatch(a -> Objects.deepEquals(arr[0], a));

System.out.println(allEqual); // true
```

Comment: I just tested this code with a 2D array. It compiles but it is returning false.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo What's your check? It's returning `true` to me for a 2d array.

Comment: I was testing the code with an array of objects rather strings. Though, the objects do return a string with the toString() method. Perhaps my results are different because I'm using an array of objects instead of strings.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo If you are using objects, make sure they implement equals() consistently.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
    if(!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method to do this is to compare the 1st string with every other string in the array.

```
public boolean allUnique(String[] arr){
    //Assuming the array has at least 1 element. 
    String s = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(!arr[i].equals(s)){
            return false;
        }   
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This approach was one of my attempts, but I actually need the method to return true rather than false after checking all values.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo you can return true after the loop. If all comparisons match then it will return true.